# Why Google Chrome for iOS can't work with Facebook JS SDK correctly?

Tags: ios, facebook, google-chrome

I read a post [here](http://www.seanshadmand.com/2015/03/06/facebook-js-login-on-chrome-ios-workaround/). And I'm encountering this issue too. When I use `FB.ui({method:'share'})` to share the content, the popup is not correctly working. But when I switched to the "old-school" way, putting a link: `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=...` it works fine.

I am just wondering why as a very popular browser, Chrome doesn't support this? Is there any technical reason for this?